# How to extend user settings file?

Tags: python, django, package

I am building a little library package, and in it I have a few apps. Is there a way I can just add the main library without having to add individual apps in the INSTALLED_APPS manually?

let say my library is "foo_lib", in there a few apps, app_bar1, app_bar2

Right now now this is what I have to do for every project.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'foo_lib',
   'foo_lib.apps.app_bar1',
   'foo_lib.apps.app_bar2',
)
```

Is there any way I can do the following instead?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'foo_lib',            # this will add app_bar1, and app_bar2 automatically
)
```

I tried to add the apps in the package.settings file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.INSTALLED_APPS += (
      'foo_lib.apps.app_bar1',
      'foo_lib.apps.app_bar2',
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to put that code in `__init__.py`? What about the sequence of the apps? Addition will probably take place at the end.

Comment: let me give init a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a list.

```
installed_apps = []
installed.append("some_app")
```

Or assign it right away

```
installed_apps = ["some_app" , "some_other_app"]
```

Or make a function for adding more apps to list

```
installed_apps = ["first_app" , "second_app"]

def addApp(content):
    if type(content) == list:    #expect a list or it will be errors
        for i in content:
            installed_apps.append(i)
```

Comment: Adding to the list is not the problem, it just that after I added it doesn't get recognized by the parent project.